# Using pygame.sprite.spritecollideany Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, attributes, pygame

I am new to python programming, and I am practicing by making a Alien Invasion game. This is a classic game configuration, there are rows of aliens you have to shot down before they make it to the bottom and collide with your ship.

Here is my `game_functions` code:

```
import sys

import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    ship.moving_right = True
elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    ship.moving_left = True
elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
    sys.exit()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
"""Fire a bullet if mimit not reached yet."""
#Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group
if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
"""Respond to key releases."""
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    ship.moving_right = False
elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
"""Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship,           bullets)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
"""Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""

# Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

#Redraw bullets behind the ship and aliens
for bullet in bullets.sprites():
    bullet.draw_bullet()
ship.blitme()
aliens.draw(screen)

# Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, bullets, aliens, ship):
"""Update position of bullets and get rid of olf bullets."""
#Update bullet position
bullets.update()
#Check for any bullets that hit an alien.
#if so, get rid of the bullet and alien

#Get rid of bullets that have disappeared
for bullet in bullets.copy():
    if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
        bullets.remove(bullet)

check_bullet_alien_collisons(ai_settings, screen, bullets, aliens, ship)

def check_bullet_alien_collisons(ai_settings, screen, bullets, aliens, ship):
"""Respond to bullet-alien collions."""
#Remove any bullets and aliens that collide.
collisons = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)

if len(aliens) == 0:
    #Destroy existing bullets and create new fleet.
    bullets.empty()
    create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
"""Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row."""
available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
return number_aliens_x

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
"""Find the number of rows for screen."""
available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - 
                        (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
number_rows = int(available_space_y / (3 * alien_height))
return number_rows

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
"""Create an alien and place it in the row."""
alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
alien_width = alien.rect.width
alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
alien.rect.x = alien.x
alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
"""Create a full fleet of aliens."""
#Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row
alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)

#Create the fleet of aliens
for row_number in range(number_rows):
    for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
        create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
"""Respond appropriately if any aliens reached an edge."""
for alien in aliens.sprites():
    if alien.check_edges:
        change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
        break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
"""Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
for alien in aliens.sprites():
    alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship):
"""Check for fleet on edge, then update positions of fleet."""
check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
aliens.update()

#Look for alien-ship collisons.
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(aliens, ship):
    print("Ship hit!")
```

And this is my game init code so I can run the functions and play the game

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from alien import Alien
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
#Initialze game, settings, and screen object.
pygame.init()
ai_settings = Settings()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
    (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion!")

#Make a ship, a group of aliens, and a group of bullets
ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
aliens = Group()
bullets = Group()

#Create a fleet of aliens
gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

# Start the main loop for the game
while True:
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    ship.update()
    gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, bullets, aliens, ship)
    gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship)
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

run_game()
```

I have most of the game done, but when I add the `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()` in the `game_functions` file, I get

> "Attribute Error: the 'Group' has no attribute 'rect'"

I know there is probably something simple I am missing, but I cannot figure it out. Sorry of the code is not correctly typed as I copied and pasted to save time when posting my question.

I am also using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and running python-3.4.3.

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback) - there are other usefull inforamtion, ie. which line makes problem. Now show this line in code.

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to put correct code - now you have incorrect indentions - so it is unreadable.

Comment: Will do! Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Pygame doc: [pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany)

This function expects single sprite as first argument, and group as second argument but you use `aliens` which is group as first argument, and ship which is sprite as second argument.

You have to change order of arguments.

---

**BTW:** next time simply use `print()` - it is most popular method (if you don't know how to debug) to check what you have in variables and see what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple I missed.  This fixed what was wrong.