# AttributeError 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

Here is a game from the book "Python Crash Course (author: Eric Matthes)"

I do exactly what the book told. But I found these problems, and why?

File "D:\pythoncode\l_one\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", **line 1586, in spritecollideany
    spritecollide = sprite.rect.colliderect**
**AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'**

Here are my codes: https://github.com/yushu-liu/Learn_Python/tree/master/Alien_Invasion

And part of my codes as follows(aline_invasion.py):

```
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group
import game_functions as gf
from alien import Alien
from game_stats import GameStats

import pygame

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Set the background Color
    bg_color = (230,230,230)

    # Make a ship, a group of bullets, and a group of aliens.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()

    # Create the fleet of aliens
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens)

    # Create an instance to store game statistics.
    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)

    # Start the main loop for the game
    while True:
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events
        gf.check_events(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)

        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
            gf.update_bullets(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens,bullets)
            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings,stats,ship,screen,aliens,bullets)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens,bullets)

run_game()
```

And another part of my codes as follows(game_function.py):

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from time import sleep

def check_keydown_events(event,ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    '''Respond to keypresses'''
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def check_keyup_events(event,ship):
    '''Respond to key releases.'''
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    '''Respond to keypresses and mouse events'''
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event,ship)

def fire_bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship,bullets):
    '''Fire a bullet if limit not reached yet.'''
    # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings,screen,ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens, bullets):
    '''Update images screen during each pass through the loop'''
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    # Redraw all bullets behind ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    # Redraw the ship and the alien
    ship.blitme()

    # When calling draw, Pygame automatically draws each element in the group
    # at the position defined by its rect
    aliens.draw(screen)

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens,bullets):
    '''Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets.'''
    # Update the latest positions of bullets
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens,bullets)

def check_bullet_alien_collisions(ai_settings,screen,ship,aliens,bullets):
    '''Respond to bullet-alien collisions.'''
    # Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)

    if len(aliens) == 0:
        # If the entire fleet is destroyed, start a new level
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings,alien_width):
    '''Determine the number of aliens that fit in a row.'''
    availabe_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(availabe_space_x/(2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x


def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    '''Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen,'''
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def create_alien(ai_settings,screen,aliens,alien_number,row_number):
    '''Create an alien an place it in the row'''
    alien = Alien(ai_settings,screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    '''Create a full fleet of aliens.'''
    # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)

    # Create the fleet of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number,row_number)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    '''Respond appropirately if any aliens have reached and edge'''
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings,aliens):
    '''Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction.'''
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1


def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    '''Respond to ship being hit by alien.'''
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
        # Decrement ship_left
        stats.ships_left -= 1

        # Update scoreboard.
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()

        # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        ship.center_ship()

        # Pause
        sleep(0.5)
    else:
        stats.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True) 

def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings,stats,screen,ship,aliens,bullets):
    '''Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen'''
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            # Treat this the same as if the ship get hit
            ship_hit(ai_settings,stats,screen,ship,aliens,bullets)
            break

def update_aliens(ai_settings,stats,screen,ship,aliens,bullets):
    '''
    Check if the fleet is at an edge, and then update the positions of all
    aliens in the fleet.
    '''
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings,aliens)
    aliens.update()

    # Look for alien-ship collisions.

    # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen.

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship,aliens):
       ship_hit(ai_settings,stats, screen, ship,aliens, bullets)

    # Look for aliens hitting the bottom of the screen.
    check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings,stats,screen,ship,aliens,bullets)
```

alien.py as follow:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    '''A class to represent a single alien in the fleet'''

    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        '''Initialize the alien an set its starting position.'''
        super(Alien,self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # Load the alien image an sets its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        '''Draw the alien at its current location.'''
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

    def check_edges(self):
        '''Return True if alien is at edge of screen.'''
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()  #  注意get_rect
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        '''Move the alien right.'''
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

ship.py as fllow:

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self,ai_settings,screen):
        '''Initialize the ship and set its starting position'''
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's center.
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        # Movement flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def center_ship(self):
        '''Make sure the ship in the center of screen.'''
        self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx

    def update(self):
        '''Update the ship's position based on the movement flags.'''
        # Update the ship's center value,not the rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Update rect object from self.center.
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        '''Draw the ship at its current location.'''
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

game_stats.py as follow:

```
class GameStats():
    '''Track statistics for Alien Invasion'''

    def __init__(self,ai_settings):
        '''Start Alien Invasion in an active state'''
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.reset_stats()
        # Start Alien Invasion in an active state
        self.game_active = True

    def reset_stats(self):
        '''Initialize statistics than can change during the game'''
        self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
```

Comment: Could you please post more information. A [mcve] or your full code would help, but given what you have posted, it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: Need your pygame.py file as well please.

Comment: You mean the version of Pygame? I use the "Pygame 1.9.4", and my IDE is Pycharm. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, was just trying to figure out what you are using.

Comment: You should update this question and post ALL code related to this. Links tend to get broken, which makes this question less useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.

**Your first one is located at line #42 of your aline_invasion.py file:**

```
gf.update_aliens(ai_settings,stats,ship,screen,aliens,bullets)
```

should be:

```
gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
```

If you look at the method declaration for `update_aliens` in the `game_functions.py` file you can see that your order was incorrect, which is important. You want to pass things into a method in the order they belong.

**Your second issue is located at line #171 of game_functions.py**

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(aliens, ship):
```

should be:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453850/using-pygame-sprite-spritecollideany-python) post, and [this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) documentation the method you are calling accepts a sprite first, then a group. You were passing the group in first, and then the sprite. Again, the order is important.

Comment: According to your suggestions, I fixed the bugs.  Yes, the order to pass things into a method are the key problems. :)  You help me a lot :)